# Print the Number series in Pyhon

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, numbers, series

Help me to solve this number series question:

input : `5`

Output:

```
2 
3 4 
4 5 6
5 6 7 8
6 7 8 9 10
```

My program :

```
rows = 6  # number of rows in the pattern
start_num = 2  # starting number for the first row

for i in range(1,rows):
    for j in range(i):
        print(start_num, end=' ')
        start_num += 1
    print()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rows = 5
for i in range(rows+1):
    for j in range(i):
        print(i + j + 1, end=" ")
    print()
```

You can try this..

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a single loop and the `range()` function:

```
rows = 6  # number of rows in the pattern
start_num = 2  # starting number for the first row

for i in range(rows):
    print(*range(start_num+i, start_num+1+i+i))
```

The `*` before the `range()` function will expand each iteration of the `range()` function into a separate parameter to `print()`.

Answer (score 1):

Recognize that

- the first number in the `i`th row is `1 + i`.
- the first number in each row increases by 1 every row (so our outer loop just needs to be `for i in range(1, n_rows+1)`
- the `i`th row has `i` elements
- the rest of the row just increments from that first number (so the inner loop will be `for j in range(first_num, first_num+i)`

```
for i in range(1, n_rows+1):
    first_number = 1 + i
    for j in range(first_number, first_number + i):
        print(j, end=" ")

    print()
```

which prints:

```
2 
3 4 
4 5 6 
5 6 7 8 
6 7 8 9 10
```